# Writing a list of issues to a given answer (with lists and embedded pictures)

Tags: discussion, editing, comments, answers, policy

I wanted to write some hints and issues regarding **Altermundus'** answer in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz/62339#62339). It would be quite longish and I'd like to include pictures and a list, so I have no idea what to do aboout it:

- It's too long and complicated for a comment
- It's not an answer, so I don't want to post it as such
- appending stuff to his answer feels wrong
- appending it to the question feels even worse

What do you think is the *(right / best / least bad)* way of doing this? Is there any standard policy regarding this?

Comment: Isn't this what chat is supposed to be for? That is, a chat room for a specific discussion? It seems really confusing that this ended up on Meta. Won't it tend to make it even harder for newcomers to figure out that stuff about TeX belongs on the main site?

Comment: On the other hand, I just realised this is from 2012. I don't even know if chat existed then....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it a meta question, possibly CW.

Comment: Will the author of the answer be automatically notified that a question has been posted at meta? I thought of posting a CW answer to the question, that I will remove later (after resolving issues) ?

Comment: I don't think there'll be an automatic notification because there's no standardized way of saying "This meta question is about post XYZ". However, if you post a comment to the main post containing the link to the meta question, the OP will be notified and everybody else can see the connection.

Comment: The CW answer model might work, too; but I think a discussion on meta is what the system has in store for such cases, and it enables us to retain the discussion/process basically forever.

Answer (score 4):

You could make it a question like (Any suggestion for improvement to xxx), and provide a self-answer.

Otherwise I don't see why adding another answer is so bad -- it may not be an answer on its own, but along with the other answer there this certainly seems as if it would compliment it.  Worst case you get some extra rep that you may feel that is not deserved. But I think if you have helped others then you  deserve it.

For instance have a look at [Bounding box is larger than expected when drawing a curved path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path/43624#43624).  I clearly marked it as a non-answer. However, based on the number of votes, I am assuming that it helped some users.