# Some issues and possible improvements "3D bodies in TikZ"

Tags: discussion

*This concerns the very nice answer of **Altermundus** in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz/62339#62339). I asked here on meta how to post this, and we agreed upon [posting it as CW on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/writing-a-list-of-issues-to-a-given-answer-with-lists-and-embedded-pictures)*.

First of all, very nice answer, especially that you try an automated version. I especially like the sphere. But there are some issues:

- You connect the upper and lower face of the truncated cone by a line connecting both at their 0° and 180° position (as did I in my answer, ahem, ahem). This is okay for cylinders and speep truncated cones, but not for flat ones: `\tikz   \tkzTruncatedCone{5}{0}{1};` will look like this:

[image]

I'll try to math out an automated way (probably **Andrew Stacey** can help :D, I remember a great cylinder answer)

- <strike>also, the lines are inconsistent: the upper circle is gray, the sides black, and the lower circle is half/half.</strike> This can be solved by first doing all the shadings and fillings, then the drawings.
- <strike>While the lower shading looks good, the upper one looks bad, it makes me think of an open tin can, not really a cylinder. I'll head for the kitchen and look for a can of beans or something to come up with a suggestion.</strike> Giving the top a lighter shading does the trick, something like this:

[image]

- <strike>I both like and dislike your cuboid approach: While its a nice idea to make certain sets of sides lighter, I dont like it to be left/right. Do you plan to make this customizable, so that I can choose the colors (or opacities) for all three sets independantly?</strike> I did it, looks like this:

[image]

- <strike>The upper part of the cone doesn't teally work:</strike> It can be improved by a left-to-right shading:

[image]
[image]

<strike>I think it could use some shading of sorts, but I don't know yet how.</strike>

I hope this helps, I'll let you know if I come up with something for the truncated cone edge problem. The code for my improvement suggesions in in my answer to the question linked.

Comment: Am I blind, or isn't there any check box for "community wiki" on Meta?

Comment: Only mods can make questions CW: I've done that.

Comment: @JosephWright: Ah, good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A little late after the question, still, may be it will help someone -- there is my solution for the bad edge cone problem:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

%polar coordinates of visibility
\pgfmathsetmacro\th{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro\az{110}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{\th}{\az}

%parameters of the cone
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\v{1}


\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=5, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={blue,thick}]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%draw axes
    \draw[axis,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (\R,0,0);
    \draw[axis,->] (\R,0,0) --(1.5*\R,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,\R,0);
    \draw[axis,->] (0,\R,0) --(0,1.5*\R,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\v);
    \draw[axis,->] (0,0,\v) --(0,0,1.5*\v) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

% % computation of tangential points
\pgfmathsetmacro\cott{{cot(\th)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\fraction{\R*\cott/\v}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{{acos(\fraction)}}

% % angles for transformed lines
\pgfmathsetmacro\PhiOne{180+(\az-90)+\angle}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PhiTwo{180+(\az-90)-\angle}

% % coordinates for transformed surface lines
\pgfmathsetmacro\sinPhiOne{{sin(\PhiOne)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cosPhiOne{{cos(\PhiOne)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\sinPhiTwo{{sin(\PhiTwo)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cosPhiTwo{{cos(\PhiTwo)}}

% % angles for original surface lines
\pgfmathsetmacro\sinazp{{sin(\az-90)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cosazp{{cos(\az-90)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\sinazm{{sin(90-\az)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cosazm{{cos(90-\az)}}

% % draw basis circle
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords,thick]{(O)}{\R}{\PhiOne}{360+\PhiTwo}{anchor=north}{}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords,dashed,thick]{(O)}{\R}{\PhiTwo}{\PhiOne}{anchor=north}{}

% % displaying tranformed surface of the cone (rotated)
\draw[thick] (0,0,\v) -- (\R*\cosPhiOne,\R*\sinPhiOne,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0,\v) -- (\R*\cosPhiTwo,\R*\sinPhiTwo,0);

% % displaying original surface of the cone (rotated)
\draw[thin] (0,0,\v) -- (-\R*\sinazm,-\R*\cosazm,0);
\draw[thin] (0,0,\v) -- (-\R*\sinazp,+\R*\cosazp,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add label at the point (0,0,\v), (0,\R,0), (\R,0,0),...?

Comment: @toandhsp just add a line like `\node at (\R,0,0) {test};`